# Can't integrate svn with Trac

Tags: svn, centos7, trac

I want to integrate an existing svn repository with Trac (on CentOS 7)

I called trac-admin like this:

```
trac-admin TracQHG3 initenv
```

After asking for the "Project Name", and the "Database connection string", it immediately started to install. This call completed without errors ("Congratulations").

I then wrote the path and type to my svn repository into section  "[trac]" of trac.ini:

```
repository_dir =  /home/morpho_svn
repository_type = svn
```

When i start tracd

```
  tracd --port 8000 /raid2/home/QHG/TracQHG3
```

i can open the Trac page on a browser.

However, there is a warning:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported version control system "svn": Can't find an appropriate component, maybe the corresponding plugin was not enabled? ). Look in the Trac log for more information.

Unfortunately, no log file is written by Trac, even though i specified a log file in trac.ini:

```
[logging]  
log_file = /tmp/trac.log
```

Also, the plugin subdirectory of my Trac environment TracQHG3 is empty.

Furthermore, the svn package for python 2.7 is installed: in python i can do 'import svn' without  any errors.

How can i properly integrate svn with Trac?

Comment: Which Trac version?

Comment: The version is tracd 1.0.13

Comment: Trac 1.0.13 is pretty old. I'd recommend moving to at least 1.2.5, or 1.4, for a better experience.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to [enable the components](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Enablingthecomponents) in `trac.ini`:

```
[components]
tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.* = enabled
```

For logging, you need to specify `log_type = file`. See [TracLogging](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLogging).

Comment: thanks - the logging works now, but adding the  ''[components]" section with the line you posted did not solve the problem entirely. The warning now says "Unsupported version control system "svn": cannot import name fs".  The log file shows a "ImportError: cannot import name fs" in svn_fs.py. I had installed both svn and fs using pip2

Comment: In a google group i found  this link:   https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#RedHat7CentOS7Fedora18andlater After installing subversion-python as suggested there everything works perfectly:no warnings, and i can browse my code.

Comment: Good catch. I thought that the subversion-python binding were installed since `import svn` succeeded for you, but that's a common problem.